# Rails 5 - belongs_to but has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am currently trying to create a system which allows for specific users to create a Course record which can be enrolled in by many other users. I've tried a few association techniques such as `has_and_belong_to_many`, `has_many :through` and number of other setups but have been unable to get it right.

Basically all that I need is the following:

- Course belongs to (is created by) a single User (foreign_id => admin_id)
- Course has many enrolled Users (Join Table?)
- User has many created Courses
- User can belong to many Courses

If you have any idea how this would be accomplished I would greatly appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Course` model to represent the course information, with a `user_id` attribute to associate with the user who created the course. I would also make an association table/model called `Enrollment` which is an association between a `User` and a `Course`. You can then do something like this:

```
#User.rb
has_many :courses
has_many :enrollments
has_many :enrolled_courses, through: :enrollments, source: :course

#Enrollment.rb
belongs_to :course
belongs_to :user

#Course.rb
belongs_to :user
has_many :enrollments
has_many :users, through: :enrollment
```

With this configuration you can call `course.user` to receive the user who created the course, but you could also call `course.users` to receive the users who are enrolled in the course. On the opposite side, you can call `user.enrolled_courses` to receive the list of courses a user is enrolled in, or `user.courses` to receive a list of courses a user has created.